# Magento 2: Database Instllation Error

Tags: magento2.3, database, error, installation

While installing database from cmd I am getting below error.

> Unable to apply data patch
>   Magento\Msrp\Setup\Patch\Data\ChangeMsrpAttributeLabel for module
>   Magento_Msrp. Original exception message: Notice: Undefined index:
>   attribute_id in D:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor
>   \magento\module-msrp\Setup\Patch\Data\ChangeMsrpAttributeLabel.php on
>   line 43

```
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:
```

> Notice: Undefined index: attribute_id in
>   D:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\module-msrp\Setup\Patch\Data\ChangeMsrpAttributeLabel.php
>   on line 43

I am also attaching screenshot of error. Can anyone please help me on that?

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution for the above problem? i am also facing this on windows system.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `vendor\magento\module-msrp\Setup\Patch\Data\ChangePriceAttributeDefaultScope.php`

comment line no 89 to 94

```
$categorySetup->updateAttribute(
            $entityTypeId,
            $attribute['attribute_id'],
            'is_global',
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL
        );
```

and in the file `vendor\magento\module-msrp\Setup\Patch\Data\ChangeMsrpAttributeLabel.php`
comment out line no 41 to 46.

```
$categorySetup->updateAttribute(
            $entityTypeId,
            $msrpAttribute['attribute_id'],
            'frontend_label',
            'Minimum Advertised Price'
        );
```

Run the setup command again to start installation.

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento-24/ --db-host=127.0.0.1 --db-name=magento-24 --db-user=root --db-password='' --admin-firstname=test --admin-lastname=test --admin-email=test@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

After installation uncomment the above files. Above solution worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such error, and having investigated this question it was found out that the problem was that in the **third-party module** (which place in app/code or vendor/)  which uses a patch to add attributes with method **$eavSetup->addAttribute()**, uses for class the interface **\Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface** instead **\Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface** and set that patch class to folder .../Setup/Patch/Schema/AddCustomAttirbute.php
It means that when we use patch to add attribute we need use interface \Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface to create patch class.